# Turn off Microsoft Explorer Touch Mouse Haptic feedback?

Tags: 11.10, mouse, mouse-scroll, microsoft

I got a new [Microsoft Explorer Touch Mouse](http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/en-us/p/explorer-touch-mouse) recently, and I like it a lot.  The one thing that drives me a little batty is the Haptic Feedback "buzzer" it uses when you scroll.  The Windows driver has a way to turn it off, and I'd like to figure out how to turn it off on my 11.10 workstation.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is simple:

This mouse has internal memory and you can turn off haptic feedback on Windows and mouse will remember your settings and on Linux (even if you change batteries).

I've tested it myself, so I know that it works.

Answer (score 3):

Here are commands for MS Explorer touch, in case someone needs them:

Haptic feedback off:
usbconfig -d N.N do_request 0x21 0x09 0x0322 0x0002 0x001B \
 0x22 0x82 0x01 0x00 0x03 0x03 0x01 0x03 0x1F 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00

Haptic feedback on:
usbconfig -d N.N do_request 0x21 0x09 0x0322 0x0002 0x001B \
 0x22 0x82 0x01 0x00 0x07 0x07 0x01 0x03 0x1F 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00

Answer (score 0):

It's not compatible with Linux fully. You can't even use the mouse on some earlier versions of Windows.

Answer (score 0):

The weird behavior happens when you swipe the blue button up.

> - Removed the button.
> - Cut the ribbon connecting the sensor/button.
> - Put the button back.

All Good!